# Flask route not receiving Ajax Call - Solved

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, ajaxform

Im trying to get 2 inputs from my HTML Form and send them to my @app.route("/sell) using Ajax.
I have followed the same steps with other routes, using the same method and I never had this issue.

This is the result and it'll give you a better understanding --> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHKko.png)

One input is a name the other a number.
Any idea what I am doing wrong? Any help is really appreciated.

HTML Form

```
<form>
    <div class="one form-group">
        <select id="stockInput" name="symbol">
        {% for stock in stocks %} 
            <option value="{{ stock.symbol }}"> {{ stock.name }}
        {% endfor %}
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select stock</option>
    </div>

    <div class="one form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="sharesInput" class="form-control" name="shares" type="number" min="1" placeholder="Number of shares">
    </div>

    <button id="sell" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sell</button>
</form>
```

AJAX Call

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {

        /* Ajax Call */
        $.ajax({
            data : {
                share : $('#stockInput').val(),
                quantity : $('#sharesInput').val()
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/sell'
        })

        .done(function(data) { 
            if (data.error){

            }
            else {

            }
        });

        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
});

        </script>
```

FLASK

```
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
        #Sell shares of stock
    username = User.query.get(int(session["user_id"]))
        # Get all stocks as objects portfolio
    stocks = Portfolio.query.filter_by(username=username.username).all()


    # Iterate over the stocks list to append the information needed in index.html table
    for stock in stocks:
        symbol = str(stock.symbol)
        shares = int(stock.shares)
        name = lookup(symbol)["name"]
        price = lookup(symbol)["price"]
        change = lookup(symbol)["change"]
        total = shares * price
        stocks.name = name
        stocks.price = usd(price)
        stocks.total = usd(total)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        # Lookup stock and save it's info
        share = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
        # Get # of shares
        quantity = int(request.form.get("shares"))

        if not share:
            return error("Stock not found", 403)
        elif quantity < 1:
            return error("Please enter the number of shares", 403)
            ... more lines of code


        
    return render_template("sell.html", stocks=stocks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the wrong variables here? Try this

```
       # Lookup stock and save it's info
        share = lookup(request.form.get("share"))
        # Get # of shares
        quantity = int(request.form.get("quantity "))
```

Comment: Good observation, that was definitely one of the issues.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @Flo I'm happy I could help you find part of the solution. Sometimes when you stare at the same problem for too long it's easy to overlook silly mistakes like that! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

My Ajax Header file in html disappeared somehow...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you!